# FlipClock.js : ease-in to initial value

Tags: javascript

I'm a PHP developer and I want to make FlipClock's inital value ease-in. I think it can be done by:

1. Making `clock.incerement()`'s interval value flexible, Based on how close is current value, to initial value.
2. Make a break when the current value was equal to initial value.

I changed this code:

```
var clock;
var initial = 5000;

$(document).ready(function() {

    clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 0, {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if(clock.getTime().time >= initial) {
                clock.stop();
            } else {
                clock.increment();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
});
```

to this one:

```
var clock;
var initial = 5000;

$(document).ready(function() {

    clock = new FlipClock($('.clock'), 0, {
        clockFace: 'Counter',
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if(clock.getTime().time >= initial) {
                clock.stop();
            } else {
                clock.increment();
            }
        }, function() {
            if ((initial - clock.getTime().time) > 1000) {
                return 1;
            } else if ((initial - clock.getTime().time) > 100) {
                return 10;
            } else {
                return 1000;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

But did not worked. What i have to do?!

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The interval value is supposed to a time in milliseconds, not a function.
One other way to do it is that you calculate the timeout value is as such

```
setTimeout(function(){
        var x = CalculateCurrentInterval(clock);
        setInterval(function() {
        if(clock.getTime().time >= initial) {
            clock.stop();
        } else {
            clock.increment();
        }
    }, x);
 })

var CalculateCurrentInverval = function(clock) {
        if ((initial - clock.getTime().time) > 1000) {
            return 1;
        } else if ((initial - clock.getTime().time) > 100) {
            return 10;
        } else {
            return 1000;
        }
}
```

I have not tried it but it should work.

Problem is that you are sending in a function where a number is expected

Comment: Thanks for your response and the `setInterval` tip. The code did not worked, I think `clock.getTime().time` is not accessible outside of `setTimeout`, so the `CalculateCurrentInverval` function won't work.

Comment: An easy way to fix that is to just send the clock object as a parameter to the CalculateCurrentInterval function.   I have updated my answer with it. I cannot test it right now however